# C++ - What's the difference between assigning a variable to another variable and assigning a variable to a reference variable?

Tags: c++, variables, reference

Say I have:

```
int a = 1
int b = a
int& c = a
```

What is the difference between `b` and `c`? Is `b` a separate copy of `a`?

Comment: This is *initialization* of a reference variable, not assignment.  Assuming you had some semicolons in there.

Answer (score 3):

The differences is:

1. b is a copy of a value --> correct.
   Where b has its own memory address where it stored its value b = value of a.
   it is simply a assignment of a variable.
2. c not copy only value of a but represent completely a.
   so after you did int&c = a; 
   now we have 2 person but same name. And you have full control of a via other name c.

Surprisingly you can check with below code

```
int main()
{
    int a =2;
    int b =a;
    int&c =a;
    int d = 3;
    c =d;
    cout <<"a="<<a<<" b="<<b<<" c="<<c<<endl;
}
```

will print

```
a=3 b=2 c=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the difference between the three. When you are assigning b to equal a, you are indeed creating a sperate copy. However, if you were to modify a, then b would stay the same. For example, if you were to increment a to 2 and then print the results, a would equal 2, but b would still be equal to one. On the other hand, since c is initialized as a reference to a.

Whenever a changes its value, c will also change its value. You can also change the value of a by changing the value of c. For more information about pointers and references, please read this article http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Heres some example code

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = a;
    int &c = a;

    std::cout << " a = " << a << ", b = " << b << ", and c = " << c << std::endl;
    a++;
    std::cout << " a = " << a << ", b = " << b << ", and c = " << c << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
a = 1, b = 1, and c = 1
(after increment) a = 2, b = 1, and c = 2
```